# Convert string to time format access 2007 query

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have been attempting to do this for some time. I have a self built timer to clock how long employees are on break or lunch during their working day. When the clock is stopped an update query stores the value in a text field as it is a string.

I'm now trying to build a query that can calculate the following:

total working time = **logged out** - **logged in**

total amount of aux time = **lunch** + **break time**

actual working hours = **working time** - **aux time**

The string for the lunch and break fields is built so it looks like the following:
Break = 00:28:01
Lunch = 01:02:13

When i build the query i have tried to use
LunchTime: Format([Lunch], "Long Time")

and
LunchTime = Timevalue([Lunch])

Neither of which have worked out.

Comment: Do [lunch] and [break time] represent the amount of time elapsed for each in hours, minutes, or seconds? Also, are you converting those values from strings to date/time before attempting to add them?

Comment: You are correct viking, sorry that was detail that got missed off from being copied and pasted across. Lunch / break = HH:MM:SS of elapsed time which is recorded from a timer built in vba on an access form. I have tried to convert them using the methods above in a query however none of them have worked out. Either producing a -1 error or just not producing anything at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you try like below

```
Format(Lunch, "h:m:s")
```

Twelve-hour clock with the uppercase letters "AM" or "PM", as appropriate.

```
Format(Lunch, "hh:mm:ss AMPM")
```

See [Here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/access-help/format-property-date-time-data-type-HA001232739.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA001228839) For more information on format specifier

Comment: Thank you Rahul I'm not able to test this until tomorrow morning but i will test it as soon as i get into work.

Comment: @ASM2701, No worries, take your time.

Comment: Thank you Rahul, your suggestion worked. I was also told by a colleague that CDate([Expression]) also works as well. Much appreciated for your help.